# P values of coefficients in rlm robust regression

Tags: r, regression, p-value, robust

I am using rlm robust linear regression of MASS package on modified iris data set as follows:

```
> myiris = iris
> myiris$Species = as.numeric(myiris$Species)
> head(myiris)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2       1
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2       1
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2       1
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2       1
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2       1
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4       1

> library(MASS)
> rmod = rlm(Species~., data=myiris)
> rmod
Call:
rlm(formula = Species ~ ., data = myiris)
Converged in 6 iterations

Coefficients:
 (Intercept) Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width 
  1.14943807  -0.11067690  -0.02603537   0.21581357   0.63793686 

Degrees of freedom: 150 total; 145 residual
Scale estimate: 0.191 
> 
> sumrmod = summary(rmod)
> sumrmod

Call: rlm(formula = Species ~ ., data = myiris)
Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.59732 -0.15769  0.01089  0.10955  0.56317 

Coefficients:
             Value   Std. Error t value
(Intercept)   1.1494  0.2056     5.5906
Sepal.Length -0.1107  0.0579    -1.9128
Sepal.Width  -0.0260  0.0599    -0.4346
Petal.Length  0.2158  0.0571     3.7821
Petal.Width   0.6379  0.0948     6.7287

Residual standard error: 0.1913 on 145 degrees of freedom
```

This does not give p.values so I calculated them as follows (using pt function of base R):

```
> dd = data.frame(sumrmod$coefficients)                             #$
> dd$p.value =  pt(dd$t.value, sumrmod$df[2])                       #$
> dd
                   Value Std..Error    t.value    p.value
(Intercept)   1.14943807 0.20560264  5.5905804 0.99999995
Sepal.Length -0.11067690 0.05786107 -1.9128044 0.02887227
Sepal.Width  -0.02603537 0.05991073 -0.4345693 0.33226054
Petal.Length  0.21581357 0.05706173  3.7821068 0.99988663
Petal.Width   0.63793686 0.09480869  6.7286751 1.00000000
```

However, these are not correct since ordinary lm function and other regression functions show that Petal.Length and Petal.Width are highly significant in this regression:

```
> summary(lm(Species~., data=myiris))

Call:
lm(formula = Species ~ ., data = myiris)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.59215 -0.15368  0.01268  0.11089  0.55077 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   1.18650    0.20484   5.792 4.15e-08 ***
Sepal.Length -0.11191    0.05765  -1.941   0.0542 .  
Sepal.Width  -0.04008    0.05969  -0.671   0.5030    
Petal.Length  0.22865    0.05685   4.022 9.26e-05 ***
Petal.Width   0.60925    0.09446   6.450 1.56e-09 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.2191 on 145 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9304,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9285 
F-statistic: 484.5 on 4 and 145 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Where is the error? Am I not using correct method to calculate p.value here?

Edit: As suggested (further) by @Glen_b in the comments:

```
> dd$p.value =  2*pt(abs(dd$t.value), sumrmod$df[2], lower.tail=FALSE)      #$
> dd
               Value Std..Error    t.value      p.value
(Intercept)   1.14943807 0.20560264  5.5905804 1.089792e-07
Sepal.Length -0.11067690 0.05786107 -1.9128044 5.774455e-02
Sepal.Width  -0.02603537 0.05991073 -0.4345693 6.645211e-01
Petal.Length  0.21581357 0.05706173  3.7821068 2.267410e-04
Petal.Width   0.63793686 0.09480869  6.7286751 3.691993e-10
```

These seem to be correct (finally).

Comment: Even if it were correct to use a t-distribution for this calculation, you don't seem to be calculating p-values correctly.

Comment: You're still not calculating correctly. Consider carefully what you're computing when the statistic is negative. Think about the use of `abs` on the statistic, and don't use `1-`, set the `lower.tail` argument the other way in the call to `pt`

Comment: I have edited the last part of my answer. Is this the correct method?

Comment: Try doing the same calculations on `lm` output and you'll see immediately if the approach works correctly.

Comment: I think I have to multiply by 2 for correct (?2-sided) P value.

Comment: That looks right. If you now look at `summary.lm` (just type that at the console), you'll find this bit of code: `ans$coefficients <- cbind(est, se, tval, 2 * pt(abs(tval),`  `rdf, lower.tail = FALSE))` ... and the last item in the arguments to `cbind` there is the p-value column in the regression table when you call `summary` on an `lm` object

Comment: I have to multiply by 2 to get 2-tailed value but when should I need to make lower.tail=FALSE ?

Comment: By using `abs` you're making the statistic positive, and you then need to look in the upper tail. So that would be "when you use `abs`"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Even if it were correct to use a t-distribution for this calculation, you don't seem to be calculating p-values correctly.

You seem to be calculating this:

[image]

when you want this:

[image]

Comment: I tried but could not figure out proper way of calculating the P value. Please see my edit in question above and advise.